# Why aren't numbers matching? They are absurdly higher than asked

Tags: javascript, html

I progressed in my code, but now for some reason the asked minimum and maximum numbers aren't matching!

I tried to fix some numbers adding *for* loops. But I think I only made it worse.

I made it on Dcoder(Phone)

```js
var rndList = [];
var rndList2 = [];

function GD() {
  var a = document.getElementById("MinS").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("MaxS").value;
  var c = document.getElementById("Min").value;
  var d = document.getElementById("Max").value;
  var e = document.getElementById("PrzNo").value;
  r = [a, b, c, d, e];
  return r;
}


var input = document.getElementsByClassName("o");

for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  input[i].addEventListener("change", function() {
    results = GD();
    var a = results[0];
    var b = (results[1] + 1);
    var c = results[2];
    var d = (results[3] + 1);
    var e = results[4];

    function raffle(MinS, MaxS, Min, Max, PrzNo) {
      function getRndInt(min, max) {
        return (Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
      }
      for (i = 0; i < PrzNo; i++) {
        rndList.push(getRndInt(MinS, MaxS));
      }
      for (i = 0; i < PrzNo; i++) {
        rndList2.push(getRndInt(Min, Max));
      }
    }
    raffle(a, b, c, d, e);
    for (i = 0; i < rndList.length; i++) {
      while (rndList[i] >= b) {
        rndList[i] = Math.round(rndList[i] / 10);
      }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < rndList2.length; i++) {
      while (rndList2[i] >= d) {
        rndList2[i] = Math.round(rndList2[i] / 10);
      }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < rndList.length; i++) {
      if (rndList[i] == 0) {
        rndList[i] = 1;
      }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < rndList2.length; i++) {
      if (rndList2[i] == 0) {
        rndList2[i] = 1;
      }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < rndList.length; i++) {
      window.alert("Serial: " + rndList[i] + " y Number: " + rndList2[i]);
    }
  });
};
```

```css
.center {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px dotted #f00;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<form action="Raffle.html" method="post" name="frm">
  <p class="center"> Minimum Serial: <input class="center o" type="number" name="MinS" id="MinS"><br> Maximum Serial: <input class="center o" type="number" name="MaxS" id="MaxS"><br> Minimum Number: <input class="center o" type="number" name="Min" Id="Min"><br> Maximum
    Number: <input class="center o" type="number" name="Max" id="Max"><br> Amount of Prizes: <input class="center o" type="number" name="PrzNo" id="PrzNo"></p>
</form>
```

I hope you can find what's wrong. I have another question, do you know some app or web page that reorganize your code? For making it more beautiful.

Comment: What is your code trying to do?

Comment: Make a raffle, random serial number and random number! And can give many prices at once

Comment: For "more beautiful" I think you are thinking of a Formatter?  If so, you can download some CLI ones, or you can use the ones built into your IDE.  I use VSCode, so I run a formatter over my code regularly to enforce coding standards.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look for it.

Comment: I dont know what you are trying to do, but i dont like that you shift the numbers by 1 space and reround EACH iteration of your while loops.  I think there is something drastically off with that.  Can you explain to us why you are doing all those for-loops with nested While loops it in?  Or what you are trying to do with your 2 lists?  It looks like something is really off after you build them.

Comment: Just keep in mind that the type of `document.getElementById("MinS").value` is a string, not a number. You'd need to convert the string to a number otherwise you'd be doing `'1' + '2' = '12'`

Comment: Fallenreaper, I think that part finished killing everything, but It used to work fine with >100 numbers, at higher numbers it just gave me a bigger number, then tried to divide and round it by 10 until it reaches the value I said that is the Max, but somehow I broke it worse

Comment: Staroselsky THX U I make a for loop in order to make this strings in integers and the while loops are trash.

Comment: The results from calling GD give you [string, number, string, number, string] - so when you add those strings on to your random number you get a concatenation instead of an addition.